# Why does role.permissions.remove() not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried to make a command to remove the `MENTION_EVERYONE` permission from all roles. It didn't work for some reason. I tried console logging which roles have the permission, and it did, but the only thing is that the permission isn't being taken away. I get no error but here is my code.

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === 'checkroleperms' && msg.author.id === 'xxxxxxxxxx') {
        var roles = msg.guild.roles.cache.array()
        var all = '{Placeholder}'
        roles.forEach(role => {
            if(role.permissions.has('MENTION_EVERYONE')) {
                all+= ', ' + role.name;
//RIGHT HERE IS THE WHERE THE PROBLEM IS!!
//Changed this to msg.guild.role.cache.get(role.id).permissions.re...
                role.permissions.remove('MENTION_EVERYONE');
                console.log(role.name);
            }
        })
        setTimeout(() => msg.channel.send(all), 500);
    }
})
```

Was there something I did wrong? Also, the bot has Admin perms and is the second highest role in the server (right under me). The point is that the command *is* running but the perms are not being removed.

**EDIT:** I realized I was only modifying the array, but nothing is happening even when  I get it from `msg.guild.roles.cache`

Comment: Could you please try replacing forEach with map and assign to a variable, I think that might help you

Comment: The command *is* running, but the permission is not being taken away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, the problem is you remove the permission but you never update the role itself.

[`role.permissions.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=remove) removes bits from these `permissions` and returns these bits or a new [`BitField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BitField) if the instance is frozen. It doesn't remove or update the role's permissions though.

To apply these changes, you need to use the [`setPermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setPermissions) method that accepts a `PermissionResolvable`, like the bitfield returned from the `permissions.remove()` method.

It's probably also better to use [`roles.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch) to make sure roles are cached.

Check the working code below:

```js
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === 'checkroleperms' && msg.author.id === 'xxxxxxxxxx') {
    try {
      const flag = 'MENTION_EVERYONE';
      const roles = await msg.guild.roles.fetch();
      const updatedRoles = [];

      roles.cache.each(async (role) => {
        if (role.permissions.has(flag)) {
          const updatedPermissions = role.permissions.remove(flag);

          await role.setPermissions(updatedPermissions.bitfield);
          updatedRoles.push(role.name);
        }
      });
      const roleList = updatedRoles.join(', ') || `No role found with \`${flag}\` flag`;

      setTimeout(() => msg.channel.send(roleList), 500);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: So role.permissions.remove() returns the bitfield so I can use it later on the role.setPermissions() function?